# Twilio WhatsApp business notification, how to replace sender USA number via Text by some configuration. I know it can be done in SMS service it

Tags: c#, twilio, whatsapp

Here in Twilio SMS from number can be replace with below code or through message service configuration from Twilio.

```cs
public static bool SendSMS(string text, string toPhone)
{
    toPhone = !toPhone.StartsWith("+") ? $"+{toPhone}" : toPhone;
    
    TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);
    var message = MessageResource.Create(
        body: text,
        from: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber("XYZ"),
        to: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber(toPhone)
    );
}
```

But in the Twilio WhatsApp business account, how do replace from number? As per the Twilio document, there is no way for alphanumeric instead of number replacement
But I hope, if someone had identified some work around then that would be really appreciated.

```cs
public static bool SendWhatsApp(string text, string toPhone)
{
    toPhone = !toPhone.StartsWith("+") ? $"+{toPhone}" : toPhone;
            
    TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);
    var message = MessageResource.Create(
        body: text,
        from: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber("whatsapp:+15000000000"),
        to: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber("whatsapp:" + toPhone)
    );
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your question. You want to change the from phone number in case it's WhatsApp? To what do you want to change it?

Comment: Ok I'm explaining that,
For example in in SendSMS function, change below line 
from: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber("Some Phone number to"), To
from: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber("Swimburger") then sender name will be Swimburger.

but in case of whatsApp change below:
from: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber("whatsapp:+15000000000").
here above naming way is possible below line:
messagingServiceSid: "GHGHJGJH87828edjhjkdhkjwhekjdew",
in above line I have configured Message service Id to make Alphanumeric sender instead of phone number. But its not working in case of USA purchase phone number.

Comment: You want to send WhatsApp messages from an Alphanumeric Sender? Unfortunately WhatsApp doesn't support this, you can only use phone numbers.
https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360026678054-Which-Twilio-Phone-Numbers-are-Compatible-with-WhatsApp-#:~:text=Are%20Alphanumeric%20Sender%20IDs%20supported,not%20support%20Alphanumeric%20Sender%20IDs.

Comment: One twilio refer link: https://www.twilio.com/blog/personalize-sms-alphanumeric-sender-id

Comment: Yes, this works for SMS (depending on the country), but WhatsApp does not support this.